# Problem understanding a subquery with the FROM clause

Tags: sql, subquery

Im having trouble understanding how can this subquery can calculate the number of rides of each bike station.
Can someone help me break it down an understand it?

```
SELECT
    station_id,
    name,
    number_of_rides. 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        start_station_id,
        COUNT(*) number_of_rides
    FROM
        bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
    GROUP BY
        start_station_id
)
INNER JOIN
    bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations ON
        station_id = start_station_id
ORDER BY
number_of_rides DESC
```

Below I attach the result of the query I run.

Comment: The subquery counts the number of rides grouped by station id. You can run that subquery independently to see it. This entire subquery is then joined to another table on station id = station id (mainly just to get station name for the final result). If you pretended that the entire inner subquery was a "table" of (Id, Count) it might help you to see how it works too.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally I understand it.